# How to retrive data from firebase without specifing key?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from my firebase database but the problem is there are more than one key that I can't specific in my query cause it can be changeable.
for example let my database be:

```
MYFIREBASEDATABASE.com/Users/UserId/date/hour/ARRAY_OF_NUMBERS(let's say 150 numbers)
```

Where day and hour can be changeable but I want all the numbers under the specific **UserId** to put them in RecyclerView.
I hope I did explained it clearly.

Comment: If you want to show all data for a given user, reading it should be fairly straightforward. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I am suck at the two parts of path that I don't know, day and time will have many different values,
I tired to save them into sharedPreference but when I get them back I can't pare them correctly and I don't know why.
so I can't put them correctly in the path of query

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

If there is any part of the path to the data that you don't know, you will have to query the common parent of that data in order to get everything below it in a single snapshot.

In your case, if you don't know date and hour, you will have to query "Users/UserId" in order to get a snapshot of everything below it.

Comment: There are plenty of code samples in the documentation.  Please make an attempt to solve the problem using what you find in docs.  If something is not working the way you expect, please post a question showing the code and what it is doing that's different than what you expect.